# Find results in certain date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, search

I am trying to only grab records that fall in a certain date range. The problem is that the timestamp and the date are stored as a string in the same cell. I want to only grab rows with a date that falls betweed 2013-05-01 and 2013-05-03.

date (stored as string)

```
2013-05-01T23:19:44
2013-05-02T23:19:40
2013-05-06T23:19:46
2013-05-06T23:15:17
```

mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 2013-05-01 AND 2013-05-03
```

Comment: Step 1) convert to a `datetime` field. Step 2) `SELECT columnList FROM tbl WHERE dateCol >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND dateCol <= '2013-05-03 23:59:59'`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: `... where date(datecol) between '2013-05-01' and '2013-05-03'`, after the datetime conversion, of course

Comment: @MarcB I wouldn't use `date()` because if there's an index on that column it won't be used.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-03'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8437c/6)**

*As @FreshPrinceOfSO absolutely correctly noted no index will be used in that case*

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO See sqlfiddle.

Comment: May want to mention that **no** index will be used here and they **really** need to use `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(`date`,1,10),'%d-%m-%Y') 
    BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-03'
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: It's because of "table". I renamed it to "table1"

Comment: You actually were missing a closing parentheses for `STR_TO_DATE` but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The string is almost valid syntax for a `datetime`.  Thus, an alternative, if perhaps slower method is to replace the 'T' with a space and then cast it to a `datetime`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
  CAST(REPLACE(`date`, 'T', ' ') AS DATETIME) 
  BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-03';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date('yourdate') BETWEEN date('2013-05-01') AND date('2013-05-03')
```

Comment: Please do provide some explanation for your answer.